# What does scale stand for in regularizers in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So my question what does `scale` stand for in:

`tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
    scale,
    scope=None)`

Here is the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/l2_regularizer) to documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scale` parameter defines how much impact your regularization should have. The higher the scale, the higher your penalty and the more impact has your regularization term.

**Important remark:**

By introducing l2-regularization, you add another hyperparameter (the scale), which should also be optimized.

Comment: It depends on which notation you are referring to, but presumably yes

Comment: By lambda I mean the number which is multiplied with the regularizing term..That is the eucledian distance

Answer (score 0):

I think scale is `lambda/n`. `n` is your number of data.

From the source code in *tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/regularizers.py*, we can find `return standard_ops.multiply(my_scale, nn.l2_loss(weights), name=name)` in line 107. The `my_scale` is just the tensor of scale. We know `nn.l2_loss()` computes half the L2 norm of a tensor without the sqrt. In other words, `nn.l2_loss()`'s output is `sum(t ** 2) / 2`.

Now we can find that scale is `lambda/n`.